# Shaul's genealogy compared to David's genealogy

Tags: tanach, genealogy, king-saul

David's full genealogy is outlined in both in [Ruth 4:18-24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ruth.4.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (although without Yehudah here) and in [Divrei Hayamim 1:2:3-15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.2.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> Yehudah-Peretz-Chetzron-Ram-Aminadav-Nachshon-Salma-Boaz-Oved-Yishai-David.

Shaul's genealogy is outlined in [Shmuel 1:9:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), in [Divrei Hayamim 1:8:29-33](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.8.29?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and in [Divrei Hayamim 1:9:35-39](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.9.35?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). There are some differences in the genealogies in the three locations, and there are different explanations, but ultimately Shaul's genealogy doesn't go all the way to Binyamin, but starts from his ancestor Afiach or possibly even a bit further back with [Matar/Matri](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.10.21?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

Why is this so?

Edit: So far I've seen that multiple Bible academics believe that this ties into the general description of Shaul in DH, much of which is negative, and this is evidence that the author of DH was a pro-Davidic, anti-Shaulic scribe. This doesn't sit well with me, because according to tradition, the author of DH is believed to have been Ezra (and perhaps also Nechemiah adding the later generations, after Ezra's death). Such a downright political bias seems uncharacteristic, to say the least.

Comment: Judah isn't in Ruth. More importantly, you don't indicate why you think the two kings should have the same coverage.

Comment: @msh210 It seems odd that one royal family would have full yichus and one wouldn't.

Comment: @msh210 is there need of any other reason? I mean, why bring any of Shaul's yichus at all? You could just say: Shaul ben Kish (because Kish himself does do something in Shmuel; he sends Shaul to look for the donkeys) of Binyamin. Yichus plays a big factor in the Davidic genealogy (both for David and other people), but with Shaul it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Harel13 Maybe the point is as you say, Shaul was chosen because he was a *tzadik*, David was chosen for his *yichus*.

Comment: In Divrei Hayamim it doesn't only go back to Afiach. It goes back to "the father of Giveon" (and in ch. 9 he's named: Ye'iel).

Comment: @TheGRAPKE That's a nice idea, but wasn't David chosen also chosen mainly for character?

Comment: @Meir Thank you, I did my best to correct the question.

Comment: @Harel13 http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba1/85.htm ויהי בעת ההיא
רבי שמואל בר נחמן פתח: (ירמיה כט) כי אנכי ידעתי את המחשבות
שבטים היו עסוקין במכירתו של יוסף,
ויוסף היה עסוק בשקו ובתעניתו,
ראובן היה עסוק בשקו ובתעניתו,
ויעקב היה עסוק בשקו ובתעניתו,
ויהודה היה עסוק ליקח לו אשה,
והקב"ה היה עוסק, בורא אורו של מלך המשיח.